Spring boot java not compiling
I am trying to compile a basic Java spring boot project with maven (running mvn clean install). I am getting this error.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-api: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported
when I run mvn -version I get the following
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.5.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
I've tried using update-alternatives to switch my Java version to 17, then 11, then 8 and changing my pom.xml file to point to those versions but I get the same error albeit with that version.
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project jeff-website-api: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 8 not supported
What am I missing?

The error message release version 21 not supported. indicates that you are not using JDK21 (set via JAVA_HOME).. also why using old plugins and old Maven version... upgrade to most recent versions of Maven 3.9.X and also the plugins (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) the message release version 8 not supported you system has one java verison via PATH but Maven uses the one via JAVA_HOME (set that correctly)

sorry for taking so long to reply, life... I thought I had set my JAVA_HOME variable correctly, this is what I see.
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64

I am also missing something in updating maven version. I've set maven version in my path in .bashrc.
export MAVEN_HOME="/opt/apache-maven-3.9.6"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH="$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin"
but I still see this when running mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64

I followed the directions from this article and it worked https://www.redswitches.com/blog/install-maven-in-ubuntu/#Method1UseapttoinstallMavenonUbuntu

Upgrade your maven version... also check the plugin versions etc. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/
